# I cannot boot Ubuntu 14.04 because HDD is too full, I can open the terminal, but cannot delete folders

Tags: boot, grub2, delete, ownership

I cannot boot Ubuntu 14.04 because HDD is too full. I can open a terminal, but cannot delete folders to make space because of read-only status.

If I check ownership, however, they appear to be my own. The same happens if I use the terminal as user, sudo or root.

Ubuntu boots until logo and goes black. I tried recovery with shift, choose the first recovery version that appears, run all the options given, but the old versions do not disappear.

For drop back to root use I did not find instructions. The sudo umount trick does not work either, I get Folder not mount.

Comment: How have you determined that is the cause of your inability to boot?

Comment: I would say, but I am no expert, that the disc is too full, so it does not boot further than the Ubuntu logo, if you boot from a live stick or from the hard disc. I also tried various boot-repair utensils, but they don't work. When trying to fix problems, there is always the answer: cannot fetch... but not because there is no connection, but no space. And I did not find a way yet how reduce the occupied (100%) space.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Create a bootable Ubuntu DVD/USB stick.

Boot from it and select `Try Ubuntu without installing`.

Once you get to the Ubuntu desktop, open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

*Fdisk will tell you which is your /, suppose it is /dev/sda1, continue run:*

```
umount /dev/sda1
fsck -y /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt 
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
apt-get clean
apt-get purge $OLDCONF
apt-get purge $OLDKERNELS
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall deborphan
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

[Source](http://howtoubuntu.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying this. The problem is that I do not get to try Ubuntu, not even with the bootable stick. If I boot with or without, it's the same. I get to the Ubuntu logo, then the screen remains black. I can open a terminal, though, what I did and now I am entering the commands.

Comment: I get dpkg errors regarding an old kernel, failed to get canonical path to /dev/sda1, there seems to be some errors due to a typo with a quite complicated routine to remove old kernels in batch. I would like to send you the screen but do not know how to do that in the terminal.

Comment: Continue with other commands. If you can start, the cleaning can be done from the system later.

Comment: Thanks once again, but the problem seems to be that I cannot download anything because the disk is full: unable to fetch archives, and those seem to be archives that are mssing

Comment: I went through all, the machine rebooted but too fast to decide about the option from the grub menu

Comment: I rebooted again, but I do not get further than the grub menu, even with the other given options.

Comment: The whole problem started when I could not stop a file recovery action by testdisk in time, and then I could not delete the files that were saved to the HDD. Read only, even if I get now that the file status is read write when I try to run the check in the grub recovery.

Comment: It is so. I rescue my files from the session live and reinstall Ubuntu formatting.

Comment: I'll google how to do that, but would be grateful for hints

Answer (score 0):

I deleted some folders with the `rm` command:

```
sudo rm -r folderName
```

After reboot I could download the offered updates, and rebooting once again, the laptop booted into Ubuntu.